# How can i stop context sensitive help from opening Help if that particular child isn't installed?

Tags: merge, chm, html-help, robohelp

Finally got help working in a merged scenario.  If there is a topic that doesn't exist, since the child .chm hasn't been installed in the directory, why does Help open anyway to a blank topic when F1 is pressed on that control?  There is a mapping and its in the redirect file and alias file for when the child .chm is installed (this is all in the master).  I want it to not open Help if it the child .chm doesn't exist.  How can i accomplish this?  or at least open it to a default topic etc?

Comment: Your problem is difficult to reproduce even though I read all previous messages. Your requirements are very special because you probably do not programm the whole package e.g. main application, add-on and different (merged) help files.

Comment: As I understand F1 application help generally, you must have application code in form of a context-ID link for each control on your main application window. So, if that control has focus and the connected CHM is working well F1 help goes to a specific topic. Having Add-On's and merged CHM with e.g. new windows programmer and help author have coordinate many things e.g. for context-sensitive help. New controls have F1 help to new topics in the slave CHM and a new context-ID is required. Having additional content to an existing functionality (same context-ID) the help author has to work only.

Comment: The issue with blank help topic (when F1 is pressed) happens with a control having focus on your Add-On window? Are the controls seperated from the main application controls? What programming language and development environment you are using?

Comment: yes, yes, c#/winforms in visual studio 2013.

Comment: @help-info.de is there a way in the redirect.xhtm file to check if the .chm child exists, and if not, do nothing?  would javascript even be able to do this check, or how else could i check to see if the child .chm is present?

Comment: Sorry, here I do not have so much experience. But, why is a control on the add-on's form not having a related topic and a missing CHM? I have not a really good idea for a solution.

Comment: you are right to think this SHOULDN'T happen.  However, i simply wanted to cover all bases, and wanted to know HOW i could do this if i needed to.   I would assume normally any control that is mapped to a slave .chm wouldn't be visible or enabled when the slave .chm's applicable plug-in is not installed.

Comment: anyway, i found out how to do some of this, but i can't get around the fact that seemingly requires the user to accept an ActiveX dialog no matter what i do.  I haven't found any way to check if the slave.chm file exists locally other than forcing the user to accept the ActiveX dialog.  This is something i don't want to do, and in fact, cannot require.  Is there some code other than this that needs ActiveX?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t(v=VS.85).aspx